# Script to put Windows 8 to sleep and wake up in 5 seconds

Tags: windows, script, sleep, power-management, wake-up

How can I put Windows 8 to sleep(standby) and then wake up in 5 seconds?

I know I can use `psshutdown -d` to sleep, but then how can it wake up on a timer?

Comment: Are making a virus? Because I see no use in such script.

Comment: Stress testing my driver in standby/wake case

Comment: Is there a problem?

Comment: I don't think you can write a script which will keep running when you computer is in sleep mode :/

Comment: Do you have another computer on the network that can run this script?

Comment: @AlexMcKenzie, no, I know about WOL, this not an option

Comment: @DavidPostill, script should program some timer to wake-up.

Comment: [How to Make Your PC Wake From Sleep Automatically](http://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/?PageSpeed=noscript)